# How do I iterate through a list by the indices of a different list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want sub_main to be made from the 'sub' list as:

sub_main = ['c','d','e','f','j','k','l','m','n','o','p'...

I have tried:

```
for i in sub:
    for j in main:
        if j == i[0]:
            while j != i[1]:
                sub_main.append(j)
```

but it is an infinite loop for some reason

```
import string
sub_main = []
main = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
sub = [['c','f'],['j','p'],['r','t']]
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the language to your post.

Comment: Consider just this part of your code `while j != i[1]: sub_main.append(j)`.  j is never incremented, and that is why it is an endless loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import string
sub_main = []
main = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
sub = [['c', 'f'], ['j', 'p'], ['r', 't']]

indexed_main = {ch: i for i, ch in enumerate(main)}

for s in sub:
    sub_main.extend(main[indexed_main[s[0]]:indexed_main[s[1]]+1])
```

Comment: Explain your ans for users help

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
sub_main = []
main = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
sub = [['c','f'],['j','p'],['r','t']]

for chsub in sub:
    amount = ord(chsub[1]) - ord(chsub[0])
    remaining = amount
    while remaining >= 0:
        sub_main.append(main[ord(chsub[0])-ord('a') + amount - remaining])
        remaining -= 1
```

This is how I would have done it, it uses the fact that every character has an ascii value.

Basically iterate over each sub-list in sub and get the amount of characters that are between the two in `chsub`.

`main[ord(chsub[0])-ord('a') + amount - remaining]` - This first finds the index of the character it should be on (c - a, for example, which is 2 which means it begins from main[2]).

Then inside that calculation I also check the difference between `amount` and `remaining` to see which character it needs to get past the initial character.

Result:
`['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't']`

---

The reason for your infinite loop has been given in a comment to your question, you never change `j` in the while, but 3 loops is too much for this issue.